# Catching exception in the script calling a method of an object that throws exception in php

Tags: php, object, exception

I am faced with this following problem.

I have a class `user`. This class has a method `verifyUser($password)`. This method  can throw an `Exception` if the `user` object is not verified or if wrong password is supplied.

I have another class `UserController`. In the method `checkCredentials()` I call the method `verifyUser` on an instance of the class `user` as shown below:

```
    try {
        $user->verifyUser(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        showMessage("Login Error-" . $e->getMessage());
        return;
    }
```

Now when any of the above stated exceptions occur in the method `verifyUser`, I get an error **Fatal error: Uncaught Exception:**

This happens though I have put the code in the `try - catch` block. I have experience in Java. And this is a standard method of exception handling. But is there something different in php?

Can please somebody explain why this is happening?

Comment: Try using `\Exception` instead of `Exception` (both in `throw` and `catch`)

Comment: as others mentioned, i'd guess its a namespace issue